# Git status --porcelain as HTML?

Tags: git, powershell

I am using powershell to gather the output of git status --porcelain and sending an e-mail with its contents if not empty,  but the result is a list of files in one line. How could I manipulate the output so that there's a 
 new line break after each file?

Here's what I am doing:

```
$output = ""

if(git status --porcelain |Where {$_ -match 'M' -or $_ -match '^\?\?' -or $_ -match 'D'})
{
    $output += "${Folder}: `n"
    $output += & git status --porcelain
    $output += "`n"
}

if (-not ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($output)))
{
    Send-Email $output
}
```

The e-mail body is something like this:

M file1.txt M file2.txt D file3.txt ?? file4.txt

thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [send-mailmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3) ? what is `Send-Email` ?

Comment: A function we built.

Comment: Found a solution: $output += (& git status --porcelain) -join "<br />"   thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered yourself, **you need [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) elements in order to see line breaks in the rendered HTML**.

- Newlines (LF characters; `` "`n" ``) are *not* enough - they are considered *incidental whitespace*, which is normalized to a single *space* on rendering.

Here's a PowerShell-idiomatic reformulation of your code that does that:

```bash
$output = 
  if (($status = git status --porcelain) -match '^(\?\?|.M|.D)') {
    @"
${Folder}:<br>
$($status -join '<br>')
<br>
"@
  }

if ($output) {
  Send-Email $output
}
```

Note the use of:

- an assignment as an expression, due to enclosure in `(...)`: (`$status = ...)` passes the value being assigned to `$status` *through*.
- an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) (`@"<newline>...<newline>"@`)
- implicit to-Boolean conversion of the `$output` value in the context of an `if` conditional: `$null` converts to `$false`, any *nonempty string* to `$true`.